# Algorithm to find a point on an infinite line in time complexity O(n)

Tags: algorithm, time, complexity-theory

on an infinite line there is a point x with unknown position. An algorithm should find this point in time complexity O(n), where n is the distance between the start point of searching s and x. The line is divided in steps. Each step has the same length.

My idea was something like this:

```
start in s
go 1 step left
if x found { 
    terminate
 }
else {
    go 2 steps right
    if x found { 
        terminate
    }
    else {
        go 3 steps left
        ...
        ..
        .
    }
}
```

But this doesn't seam like O(n).

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: It will be helpful, what exactly 'x found' means? And any other properties of the line and step.

Comment: It depends on the time complexity of the operation "go x steps left/right", is it O(1) or O(x)?

Answer (score 2):

You have discovered the right algorithm for the job.

> But this doesn't seam like O(n).

This algorithm is precisely O(n), because for each value of `k` between 1 and `n` it probes exactly twice - once on the right at the position `x+k*s`m, and once on the left at the position `x-k*s`. This means that the algorithm is O(2n), but since the constant factor is always excluded in big-O notation, your algorithm is O(n).

Answer (score 0):

I guess there's some reason this "algorithm" has to "walk" from s, visiting only one place at a time, and the total time is equal to the distance walked...   Otherwise you'd just move two points out from s in both directions until one of them finds the target. (I think this is what @dasblikenlight thinks you did)

If I'm reading your question correctly, then, your algorithm is on the right track, but to do this in linear time, you have to increase the distance walked in each direction exponentially when you turn around.

For instance, you could go right 1, left 2, right 4, left 8, right 16, etc.  Each time you turn around, you walk over the previously covered area and then go the same distance again.

Lets say you finally find x while walking 2^m steps in some direction.  The total distance you've talked is at most the sum of all 2^p for p=1...m.  This works out to 2^(m+1)-1.

Furthermore you know that x is more that 2^(m-2) steps away from s, because otherwise you would have found it on an earlier pass.

2^(m+1)/2^(m-2) = 8, so the total distance walked is less than 8n, which is certainly in O(n)

Answer (score 0):

think of infinite line as infinite element array and you are asked to start from an arbitrary point,

1. traverse some finite distance `d` on right and check each index if value is found, if found declare `SUCCESS` and `exit`, if not found till index `d` goto step 2
2. traverse left till distance `2d`, start checking value from `currentPos-d` distance only, as indexes from `currentPos` till `currentPos-d` are already checked in previous iteration, if value found at any index declare `SUCCESS` and `exit`, if not found till `currentPos-2d`, set `d=2d`, goto `step 3`.
3. Traverse right till distance `2d`, start checking value after `currentPos+d` distance only, as indexes from currentPos till `currentPos+d` are already checked in previous iteration, if value found at any index declare `SUCCESS` and `exit`, if not found till `currentPos+2d`, set `d=2d`, goto `step 2`.

This way you can avoid O(nx(n-1)) and resolve to O(n) , as you are NOT repeatedly checking values at each iteration, in step 2 and 3 where you are avoiding to check values from currentPos-d and currentPos+d , further when you set d=2d, thats where and how you are reducing algo complexity to O(n).